# Find the singulartiy of $\frac{1}{(\pi + z)\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{\pi z}$

Tags: analytic-functions, singularity

Find the singulartiy of $\frac{1}{(\pi + z)\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{\pi z}$.

I'm trying to use the strategy shown in the following question (2nd answer):

[Locate and classify the singularity of $\frac{e^{z-1}-1}{z^4-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482307/locate-and-classify-the-singularity-of-fracez-1-1z4-1/4482320?noredirect=1#comment9400355_4482320)

So my singularities are: $-\pi, 0, \pi k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If I rewrite the function as follows:

$\frac{\pi z - (\pi+z)\sin(z)}{(\pi + z)\sin(z)\pi z}$. I do see that $0$ is a zero of the function in the numerator. But how can I derive the multiplicity of 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $0$, you have$$\pi z-(\pi+z)\sin(z)=-z^2+\frac\pi6z^3+\cdots$$and$$(\pi+z)\sin(z)\pi z=\pi^2z^2+\pi z^3+\cdots$$and therefore$$\frac{\pi z-(\pi+z)\sin(z)}{(\pi+z)\sin(z)\pi z}=\frac{-z^2+\frac\pi6z^3+\cdots}{\pi^2z^2+\pi z^3+\cdots}=\frac{-1+\frac\pi6z+\cdots}{\pi^2+\pi z+\cdots}.$$So, $0$ is a removable singularity, since, near $0$, you can express your function as a quotient of two analytic functions such that $0$ is not a zero of the denominator.

Near $-\pi$ you have$$\pi z-(\pi+z)\sin(z)=-\pi^2+\pi(z+\pi)+\cdots$$and$$(\pi+z)\sin(z)\pi z=\pi^2(z+\pi)^2-\pi(z+\pi)^3+\cdots$$Since $0$ is not a zero of the numerator and it is a double zero of the denominator, it is a double pole of the quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\lim_{z\to 0}(z-0)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{(\pi + z)\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{\pi z}\right)=0,$$
so there is no pole, but a removable singularity.
That's the Riemann's principle about removable singularities.

Comment: But how can one derive that $-\pi$ is indeed a pole of order 2?

Comment: Note that $\pi$ is not a pole or zero of the numerator so we are not worried about it. Just take $g(z)$ equal to the denominator and study the derivatives in the point. The first nth derivative that is not zero at that points gives us that the point is a zero of order $n$, so it's a pole of order $n$ for $1/g$, so also is for our function

Comment: So, in general if I have $f/g$ I first need to check for the zeros of $g$. If those zeros are not zeros of $f$ I do not have to care about $f$ and can study only $g$ (by looking at the n-th derivatives). Correct? If, however, a zeros of $g$ is a zero of $f$ as well then it may be a removable singularity, right? That I can check with the Riemann-method and control if the limit is 0. Is there an approach if $g$ has a zeros which $f$ has as well and the limit in the Riemann Test is not $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Also you must be careful because $z_0$ could be a pole for the numerator, for example $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z}$. In that case you have to study the laurent series

Comment: Is it equivalent to the Riemann principle if I just check that the limit exists and is finite?

Comment: No, in that case it will be a pole of order $1$.

Comment: I'm confused. Because there are few videos where they check in the case of removable singularity just for the limit i.e. $\lim_{z \to z_0}f(z)$ (if that limit exists and is bounded) and not as in the Riemann principle: $\lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$.

Comment: Yes that's the same. I though you were talking about the $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$ being finite but not zero. But yes if $\lim_{z\to\ z_0}f(z)$ is finite then is holomorphically extendable over $z_0$, that is equivalent to $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=0$